What is the effect of sizeof for hypothetically oversized objects?
Suppose we have the source:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct foo
{
    char b ;
    char a [ SIZE_MAX ] ;
} ;
int main ( void )
{
    const size_t z = sizeof ( struct foo ) ;
    printf("%zu\n", z);
    return 0 ;
}

What behavior can be expected from the compiler with respect to sizeof (struct foo)? There can be no object of type struct foo, since it's size would be greater than SIZE_MAX.
I do not find this case covered in the discussion of the sizeof operator in the (draft) C17 Standard (N2176).
I am using a version of gcc (outdated) that claims to adhere to the C11 standard (and, AFAICT, it does). It fails to compile and reports that struct foo is too big. That seems reasonable, but is such source guaranteed not to compile, given adherence to the standard? I would be interested in answers specific to particular standards.
$ gcc --version | head -1
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
$ gcc -c -Wall  -o /dev/null  oversize.c
oversize.c:6:10: error: sizeof array `a` is too large
   char a [ SIZE_MAX ] ;
        ^


no need to be vague, show the gcc compiler version please, command line used etc, tks

Would the wrapping logic as ((size_t)SIZE_MAX) + ((size_t)1) come into play?

Unrelated: you can find the latest C23 draft here ==> https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3220.pdf

@ticktalk RE: "version... command line:" Done.

What behavior can be expected from the compiler with respect to sizeof (struct foo)? I would expect the behavior to be undefined, so no/any behavior can be expected.

I would expect a compliant compiler to fail to compile.  If code compiled, then sizeof ( struct foo ) is undefined behavior (UB).

As I read the C spec, struct foo_minus1 {  char b ;  char a [ SIZE_MAX - 1] ; } ; should also fail as the address after the object must be computable.

If sizeof ( struct foo ) were an arithmetic expression computing the hypothetical size of struct foo by adding the sizes of its various members and padding, it would be governed by the rules for unsigned integer arithmetic, which would wrap results modulo SIZE_MAX+1, per C 2024 6.2.5.
However, sizeof is not specified to perform arithmetic as if with the + operator. It seems more appropriate it is governed by this rule in C 2024 6.5.1:

If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

sizeof is defined to produce the size of its operand. The size that struct foo would have is not in the range of size_t, which is the result type of sizeof. Therefore, the behavior is undefined.
Exceptional conditions have been undefined throughout all the C standards, although the wording was a bit different in C 1990, referring to an “exception” occurring instead of an “exceptional condition.“

(C 2024 6.5.1), as quoted, appears identical to (N2176 6.5-5 "Expressions").

It may also be worth mentioning that according to §5.2.5.2 ¶1 of the ISO C23 standard, implementations are only required to support object sizes up to 32767 bytes.
